# Триггер на обновление

Tags: sql, sql-server

Заранее извеняюсь за грязь в коде но подругому не умею,в общем,
есть триггер

```
    USE [ERP]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[Потребность]    Script Date: 11.05.2016 19:59:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Trigger [dbo].[Потребность] 
ON [dbo].[Ведомость_материалов]
FOR insert
AS 
Declare @a int;
Declare @b int;
Declare @с int;
Declare @v int;
Declare @q int;
select  @с=Материал,@v=Колличество_на_складе from Ведомость_материалов 
select  @a=sum(количество)  from Заявка where Статус='В пути' AND Заявка.Наименование_детали=@с  group by Наименование_детали 
select  @b=количество from План  where План.ID=@с 
select @q=Наименование_детали from Журнал_прихода

update Ведомость_материалов set Чистая_потребность=@b-isnull(@a,0)-@v where Ведомость_материалов.Материал=@q
```

его задача расчитать Чистую прибыль путем простой формулы

---

> ***Чистая потребность=Количество по плану-количество(только те которые*** 
>   ***еще в пути)-количество на складе***

---

проблема вот в чем,когда **Чистая потребность** должна быть равна нулю,то она принимает значение чистой потребности другой детали

Comment: Почему вы во всех своих запросах постоянно выбираете из таблиц все записи, а не те, что реально были вставлены при данном вызове триггера. Почему не используете таблицу inserted, которая как раз содержит все необходимые вам данные. У вас не должно быть НИ ОДНОГО запроса select без условия where не из inserted

Comment: @Mike , в inserted не содержится количество по по плану и  количество из заявки

Comment: `select  @с=Материал,@v=Колличество_на_складе from Ведомость_материалов ` — у Вас в таблице `Ведомость_материалов` всего одна запись? Если нет, то Вам здесь действительно требуются данные случайной записи из этой таблицы? Тот же вопрос и про таблицу `Журнал_прихода`.

Comment: @Yaant,нет,там множество записей

Comment: @Sergei А Ваш запрос присваивает переменным `@c` и `@v` значения какой-то одной из них, причем какой именно — заранее неизвестно.